# dataframe of type List to display trailing zeros in R

Tags: r

I have a nasty problem that bugs me a lot.

I have a list (dataframe) that looks like this:

```
    a            b           c
1   1.00234    1.05667    1.00198
```

I want to round the numbers of this dataframe to two decimal number.
But the trailing zeros have to be kept like the following:

```
    a            b           c
1   1.00         1.06       1.00
```

I tried the round and `printf()` and so on, it doesn't work, because my data is a list. It can't be coerced. However, I'd like to keep my data structure.

Anyone of you know how to solve this? I appreciate it very much!!!

Comment: You have one `data.frame`?  Or a `list` of data frames?

Comment: Only one dataframe. data.frame(c(1.00234, 1.05667,1.00198)) like this one. How can you show it as I pointed out above?

Comment: So a single-column data frame?  Your post displays the data as three columns...

Comment: sorry, it's three columns as it showed above. But that shouldn't be the problem right? You can transpose it if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1.00234, b=1.0567, c=1.00198, d=99999, e=.00001)

format(round(df, 2), nsmall=2)
#      a    b    c        d    e
# 1 1.00 1.06 1.00 99999.00 0.00
```

Comment: Cool. If any of your columns are non-numeric, you'll need to do something more like this:  `data.frame(lapply(df, function(X) if(is.numeric(X)) format(round(X,2), nsmall=2) else X))`

Comment: really great explanation. This is too advanced. I need to look into it. awesome man! appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to effectively loop the `round`ing over the columns.  I'm having trouble determining exactly what your data looks like. But if it's a `data.frame` with numerous rows and columns, see this example.  You'll need to convert back to class data.frame if that matters, as this method of `sapply` will coerce the data frame to a matrix.

```
> dd <- data.frame(a = runif(6), b = runif(6), c = rnorm(6))
> dd
          a         b          c
1 0.3992252 0.9905755 -0.2557345
2 0.5052276 0.7990887 -0.7557547
3 0.3215714 0.1134675 -0.4389722
4 0.1794793 0.5372685  1.1657751
5 0.9543305 0.8908360 -1.5966621
6 0.9525730 0.5991279 -0.4819168

> as.data.frame(sapply(dd, round, 2))
     a    b     c
1 0.40 0.99 -0.26
2 0.51 0.80 -0.76
3 0.32 0.11 -0.44
4 0.18 0.54  1.17
5 0.95 0.89 -1.60
6 0.95 0.60 -0.48
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much for your effort. Although your answer doesn't really work on my example. But maybe it has to do with my dataframe. Josh's approach worked perfectly. I don't really know why his worked. But I learned a lot from yours too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a=1.00634;
    float p=round(a*100); float q=p/100;
    printf("%.2f",q);   
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: appreciate your answer, sorry, maybe my bad. My question is R related. not C++.